# Can't autowire a component into a utility class

Tags: java, spring, groovy

I'm having a problem autowiring a component into a utility class. The utility class initially had static methods in it, but then I just made them instance methods.

I defined the utility class with **@Component** and within the class put in

```
class MyUtilityClass {
@Autowired
ExistingComponent existingComponent
...
}
```

The package the utility class is in is under the specified parent directory for **@ComponentScan**, where *value*="top-level-directory" that also contains the packages for all the other autowired components.

To get the utility class to run I had to pass the *ExistingComponent* into a constructor for the utility class.

Using Spring 4.1.6.

This is probably something basic, but it's not clicking. What am I missing here?

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**

The class that is calling the utility class looks like the following:

```
class UsingClass {
@Autowired 
MyUtilityClass myUtilityClass
...
    def method1() {
    String variable1 = "some data"
    myUtilityClass.utilityMethod(variable1)
    ...
    }
}
```

Originally I had the internal utility method as static and tried to use the utility class without autowiring it.

Comment: Show the class where you're calling the methods on `MyUtilityClass`.

Comment: what about the other classes in the same package . do they support autowire

Comment: Edit the calling class into the question.

Comment: The classes in the same 'util' package don't do any autowiring. Checked that first!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have this somewhere within your beans XML configuration files?

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.your.package" />
```

The **base-package** indicates where your components are stored.

This allows Spring to scan the package so that it can find the beans annotated with `@Component`.

This is explained in more depth [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-scanning-components/).

Comment: Not using XML. Using the **@ComponentScan** annotation, the _value_ attribute is set to a directory above the 'util' directory and above the other component directories. I.e., if _value_="com.my.top-level-dir", the packages that are autowired are in packages "com.my.top-level-dir.pkg1", "com.my.top-level-dir.pkg2", etc... The utility class is in a package "com.my.top-level-dir.util".

Comment: I see. Yeah I wasn't sure if you were running entirely annotation driven. You atleast have the annotation driven tag to run annotations right? I believe atleast that much is needed for @Autowired. I'll look into this more today and report any findings back. Thanks for the update!